# Kreysig 2.7 Problem 13

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

A real matrix $A=(\alpha_{jk})$ with $r$ rows and $n$ columns defines an operator $T:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^r}$ by means of $$y=Ax$$

When $r=n$, a compatible norm is defined by $$||A||=(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\alpha_{jk}}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I can prove the $\leq$ but I can't prove it for $\geq$ part.

Any hint? (My idea is to find an example of a $x$)

Comment: What do you want to prove?

Comment: to prove the norm of the operator is as given above.

Comment: That is called the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hilbert-SchmidtNorm.html  It is not the "operator norm", so you cannot prove that it is.  It is a "compatible norm" in the sense http://dictionary.sensagent.com/Matrix%20norm/en-en/#Compatible_norms  That is, inequality $\le$ holds, but not $\ge$.